# Can I Modify Ubuntu 16.04.03 and sell it for Profit?

Tags: license, legal

I am a software developer. I have been using Ubuntu 16.04.03 from several weeks, I had well modified it, thanks to the open source who had allowed me to do so.IT is modified to a level which can beat its' competitors even it could bring a revolution in OS world specially for Linux distros, if the authority will allow me to sell my modified Ubuntu then a huge profit could be earned and no matter if shares will be divided among me and authority involved, well I had googled it but there were lots of confusing links I want its' sure answer.

Comment: Yes, you can sell copies of the software, but so can anyone else. That is the nature of the license. Furthermore, you'll have to give everyone the source code from which the binaries you sell are made. You may have to remove the Ubuntu trademarks, as they come with a trademark policy.

Comment: @muru: That's even better!

Comment: See https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/selling.en.html

Answer (score 0):

You can sell your modified Ubuntu, however you will have to release it under GPL licence, and thus it must be open-source. See a more [detailed discussion here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/47048/40130).

Edit: as David Foerster points out, Ubuntu contains components with different licences (GPL is just the most common one). Depending on what you distribute, you will have to comply with the licences of every component you use.

Comment: No, it doesn't have to be GPL. It depends on what is being modified. However, modifying Ubuntu means it is no longer Ubuntu, and so you will no longer have the right to use the trademarks or claim that it is Ubuntu.

Comment: See https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/selling.en.html